# Redirect after first login in moodle

Tags: redirect, authentication, moodle

when I'm importing users from a csv file, i just import main fields like username,password,email...
now i need that after this importing, user should receive a confirmation email in which is required to fill up all the custom required fields.

What would be the best way?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could write a local plugin that subscribes to the user creation event (look at the events API) and sends the email.